# Returning a big number in for loop

Tags: c++, algorithm

I was working on a problem and got stuck into this silly error and I can't solve it.
Basically I am using a for loop and reading a character from stream. When the character is '-' I am decreasing my integer by one and when it is '+' I am increasing it by one.
I used an unsigned int because I don't want negative numbers. Here is an example of code:

```
char x;
unsigned int number = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    cin >> x;
    if (x == '-'){
        number--;
    }else if (x == '+'){
        number++;
    }
}
cout << number;
```

And it shows a number something like this 4294967293.

Where is the problem?

Comment: What is n's value?

Comment: That's due to a wraparound. If you decrement `0`, you generate the largest representable number. For 32 bits, thats 4294967295.

Comment: So I must use a normal integer?

Comment: @vladponcea If you want to be able to use negative numbers, yes.

Comment: @vladponcea: you can for example add an extra check that you simply can not decrement for `number` is zero.

Comment: First decide what should be the behavior of the program if the number is zero and they press -.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your problem statement says that final resultant `number` will not be `negative`, it does not mean that the intermediate numbers will also be `positive` only. Because, there can be a sequence of streams with characters like `- + +` which leads to values like: `0, -1, 0, 1`. Here, final answer is `positive` but intermediate numbers are still `negative`.

Now, you are trying to hold both `positive` and `negative` numbers in `unsigned int` datatype which is leads to wrong output here in above example. Because, if number is `0` and you try to apply negation, it will be `4294967295` (maximum value for a variable of type unsigned int) instead of being `-1`.

So, instead of using `unsigned int` datatype , you can use `int` datatype as suggested by Kaidul.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to wrapping around of `unsigned` data type. Since it's `unsigned`, it can't be negative. So negation operation wraps around and yields boundary values of 32 bit integer.

Replace

```
unsigned int number = 0;
```

with

```
int number = 0;
```